# Ensuring long digits are maintained in CSV output

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

I have an R data frame which needs to be saved as a csv file however one numeric column changes its format when saved as a csv file.

I have a character column named ID as below:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = as.character(1181050000000002, 1189050000000003),
                 Other = c("John", "Mary"))
```

When I save as a csv file on r, it changes to

```
write.csv(df, "df.csv", row.names = FALSE)

df <- read.csv("df.csv")

df$ID

ID
1181050000000000
1189050000000000
```

The output when I open the csv file should appear as original

```
ID
1181050000000002
1189050000000003
```

Comment: try with `readr::write_csv(df, "df.csv")`. It worked for me

Comment: @patL I could not replicate it with `write_csv`, still get the same rounding as described in OP

Comment: @patL tried the same code but still appears to have the same issue

Comment: the key is to change `scipen` in the options, see @patL's answer now

Comment: @FonsMA I think I had this option already set.

Comment: @patL I was looking for the correct option to change for this but you beat me to it ;) I thought it was `digits` at first...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that worked for me using `readr`:

```
library(readr)

write_csv(df, "df.csv")

options(scipen=999)

df1 <- read.csv("df.csv")

df1

#                ID
#1 1181050000000002
#2 1189050000000003
```

And here's a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: the issue is when I save the ouput as a csv file and open the cvs file. The data appears in the scintific format.

Comment: This is just what I did and the image shows that it worked. Copy the code (not the image) and check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try library `bit64`

`dt$ID <- as.integer64(dt$id)`

It is a high precision integer. Usually works well with this long number issues (if all your id are combinations of digits, of course)