# Numeric values change when written to txt file

Tags: r, file

I'm trying to extract the first column from [this file](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aj9lfQS8qKqwnWiXL_t6pVaPHu0y). It is a sequence of 16 numbers that should be treated as string. The problem is when I write the data to a text file certain values seem to have changed. Following is the code I'm using.

```
dataMaster = read.table("Master.txt", header = F, colClasses = rep("character",67))

write.table(dataMaster$V1, "sequence.txt", col.names = F, row.names = F, 
            quote = F, sep = "\n")
```

Below is an example. I'm taking the same two rows 261182, 261183. There are quite a few occurrences of the same error. It seems like when I write the file number 9 gets replaced with number 0.

[image]

The master file was processed in a Mac environment and I'm working in a Windows environment.

Comment: So, the first variable of both `master` and `sequence` are suppose to be the same?

Comment: I'm basically extracting the first column from the master file and writing it to sequence.txt

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked duplicate also gets it wrong, lol.

Comment: @HongOoi, fourteen upvotes though! Now I do feel wronged...xD Life was easier in the halcyon days of 2012...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach, if you want to `sequence` to be a `character`, is to specify your `colClasses`:

```
library(dplyr)

dataMaster %>% 
  select(1) %>% 
  write.table("sequence.txt", col.names = F, row.names = F, 
              quote = F, sep = "\n")

sequence <- read.table("sequence.txt", colClasses = "character")

dataMaster[c(261182, 261183), 1]
#[1] "9171513174761179" "9171513174771179"

sequence[c(261182, 261183), ]
#[1] "9171513174761179" "9171513174771179"
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @HongOoi I've changed the accepted answer. Sorry about the confusion. It seems I did not understand the difference as well. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to operate with character strings, please see patL's answer below. What follows was my answer for treating the sequence of numbers as numeric.

---

You may need to increase the `scipen` value under `options`:

```
options(scipen=999)
```

This increases the amount of precision digits beyond the default 15 when you output the [numbers to any format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54647922/ensuring-long-digits-are-maintained-in-csv-output?noredirect=1#comment96087910_54647922).

In terms of input, if you were specifying `character` only to avoid losses, note that you should instead change the `numerals` argument of `read.table` to `"no.loss"` as the default (first option) will lead to loss without warning. I've copied the relevant text from the help page `?read.table` below.

```
read.table(..., numerals = c("allow.loss", "warn.loss", "no.loss"))
```

> ```
>         string indicating how to convert numbers whose conversion to
>         double precision would lose accuracy, see type.convert. Can be
>         abbreviated. (Applies also to complex-number inputs.)
> ```

Comment: @FonsMA I've tried with options(scipen=999) and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: This is a bad answer. If the data is character, then it should be read and written as character, rather than fiddling with significant figures.

Comment: I stand corrected, I missed the "should be treated as a string" several times... I can't delete a "correct" answer, so I've edited to reflect your point and indicate patL's answer below

Comment: No worries. Props for being able to accept criticism; a lot of people would fly off the handle....

Comment: @FonsMA just to be clear for the future references I will mark the patL's answer as the correct answer.